# Unable to cast object of type 'InternationalRowViewDetailsModel' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have a class as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataBinding.Schemas.Scenario.ViewModels
{
    public class InternationalRowViewDetailsModel: IEnumerable
    {
        public InternationalRowViewDetailsModel()
        {
            Country = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object, object>();
            RateEUR = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object, object>();
            RateGBP = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object, object>();
            RateUSD = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object, object>();
        }

        public Dictionary<object, object> Country { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<object, object> RateEUR { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<object, object> RateGBP { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<object, object> RateUSD { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return (IEnumerator)this; }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to iterate through the values of InternationalRowViewDetailsModel as follows:

```
foreach (InternationalRowViewDetailsModel currentRow in viewModel)
{
   Row newRow = FillInternationalNumberRow(itemRow, currentRow);
   tableNode.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

I want to use foreach and send each current row to the method FillInternationalNumberRow which fills in columns of a table.

```
 private static Row FillInternationalNumberRow(Row rowTemplate, InternationalRowViewDetailsModel internationalViewModel)
        {
            Row newRow = rowTemplate.Clone(true) as Row;
            int currentCell = 0;
            if (newRow != null)
            {
                newRow.Cells[currentCell++].FirstParagraph.Runs[0].Text = internationalViewModel.Country.ToString();
                newRow.Cells[currentCell++].FirstParagraph.Runs[0].Text = internationalViewModel.RateEUR.ToString();
                newRow.Cells[currentCell++].FirstParagraph.Runs[0].Text = internationalViewModel.RateGBP.ToString();
                newRow.Cells[currentCell++].FirstParagraph.Runs[0].Text = internationalViewModel.RateUSD.ToString();
            }
            return newRow;
        }
```

But I get the following error:
Unable to cast object of type 'DataBinding.Schemas.Scenario.ViewModels.InternationalRowViewDetailsModel' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'

Comment: return (IEnumerator)this; you never defined an enumerator. rather you are trying to cast this to IEnumerator

Comment: you seem to want to use the class InternationalRowViewDetailsModel in a foreach loop, but from the code it's not clear what you want to be yielded from the foreach loop.

Comment: @ Scott Morken  I am trying to use the foreach loop and traverse through each row of InternationalRowViewDetailsModel.

Answer (score 2):

Your class implements `IEnumerable`:

```
public class InternationalRowViewDetailsModel: IEnumerable
```

Yet you're trying to cast it as `IEnumerator`:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return (IEnumerator)this; }
```

The object you want to iterate through must implement `IEnumerator` as well so that the code knows how to traverse your collection.

Answer (score 0):

You are not implementing the interface properly. Here is a type which implements `IEnumerable`:

```
public class A : IEnumerable {
   private List<string> items = new List<string>();

   public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
      return this.items.GetEnumerator();
   }
}
```

In the above code I am simply returning the `IEnumerator` of the internal list.

Keep in mind when you use the `IEnumerable` it will yield items of type `Object`. So even though in the above I have a `List<string>`, when traversing it, it will return type `Object`. Try to use the generic one `IEnumerable<T>` if possible to avoid boxing and unboxing.